# How to override stale cache while cache is not expired in varnish

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

After reading the varnish 4.1 document, I found that I can set 'req.hash_always_miss' to true to force a 'miss' while looking up cache and fetch the latest content in backend.

But I still can not figure out how to configure the vcl file.

below is the config file in my server.

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

acl purgers {
    "localhost";
}

sub vcl_recv {

    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purgers) {
                return(synth(405,"Not allowed."));
        }
       set req.hash_always_miss = true;        

    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    set beresp.ttl = 1d;

}
```

while backend content change, I want to refresh the varnish cache before it get expired. 
so I call curl -X PURGE http://localhost:6081/path/to/my/content
I do get the latest content as a response, but I found that varnish cache is still not get refreshed. Can someone tell me why? thanks

Comment: Maybe this helps: "hash_always_miss will replace the current variant, and nothing else. The "old" other variants of the same hash are still valid
objects and will be served to a client indicating request headers matching the varied headers."

Comment: Thanks Ronald, so you mean I can not refresh the "old" cache while it is not expired ?

Comment: No, this is not what I mean. Try using "return (purge);" instead of "set req.hash_always_miss = true;" in your VCL. 'purge' removes all 'Vary:'-variants of the cached object and I am not sure if 'hash_always_miss' does this too in Varnish 4. But if it works with 'purge' than you know this is the problem you are experiencing when using 'hash_always_miss'.

Comment: If you do not know what I am talking about regarding 'Vary'-variants read this: http://mark.koli.ch/understanding-the-http-vary-header-and-caching-proxies-squid-etc

Comment: That article really helps, thanks again!